# How do I move window buttons( close,maximise,minimise) to the right in latest Ubuntu?

Tags: unity, themes

As the title suggest, I want to ask how do I change the alignment of window buttons. I am currently using Ubuntu 17.04 x64. I searched about the topic a bit in Google, what I found is that it was supported in Ubuntu 16.04 via Unity Tweak Tool, but currently  is no longer supported. So, is there any way to do it??

PS- I'm new to Linux in general,so do excuse me for asking silly questions.

Answer (score -1):

From Ubuntu 14.04 onwards, you can't change the position of the minimise, maximise and close buttons in Unity. It has been hardcoded. Please refer to [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1622043). Your best bet would be to use a different desktop manager. I would recommend cinnamon